# Finding distance circles are apart in 1 axis when offset certain amount

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to be able to calculate the .0727 in the picture with varying diameters given the diameter of both circles and the offset of the edges (.004 in this case) but I am really struggling with how to do this or what to even search for.  The angle between the circles is also unknown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle, let us denote it with $\alpha$,  between by the line connecting the centers of two circles and the vertical is a useful input to calculate the distance you are interested.

Let us denote the radii of the two circles as $r$ and $R$ (for the upper and lower circumference respectively). Then the following equation holds
$$ (R + r) \sin \alpha = 0.0727 $$

$  \alpha$ is found from the offset.
First note that the offset is given by two contributions:

1) vertical distance between the highest point of the lower circumference and the point in common between the two circumferences

2) vertical distance between the point in common between the two circumferences and lowest Point of the upper circumference

The offset $o$ can then be calculated as
$$ o = R - R \cos \alpha +  r - r \cos \alpha = R (1 -\cos \alpha ) + r (1 -\cos \alpha) = (R + r)(1 -\cos \alpha) $$

Could you take it from here?

Comment: That's so simple now, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Since I am already finding the lengths of the triangle this would also work? sqrt((R+r)^2-(R+r-offset)^2)

Comment: It should indeed